# Are "start/begin [infinitive]" and "start/begin [gerund] really interchangeable?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

[Many](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/begin-to-work-and-begin-working.2178258/) agree that there's no difference "between start/begin + infinitive" and "start/begin + gerund."

But in sentences like "When [we first started to talk/started talking](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=we%20first%20started%20talking%2C%20we%20first%20started%20to%20talk&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwe%20first%20started%20talking%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwe%20first%20started%20to%20talk%3B%2Cc0)," the gerund version is a lot more common.

Maybe grammatically, both versions are correct. But colloquially, the gerund version is more common?

Comment: Yes, I think the gerund version is more informal. My first thought was that _it started to rain_ was more idiomatic than _it started raining_, but that may be because I've often seen it in books, and in real life people would be just as likely to say _started raining_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there are zero differences. "We first started talking" is easier to say than "we first started to talk".

Non-native has this problem of analysing things too deeply

Comment: Can you povide some sources to justify this as it does not seem correct to me.